combine vectors into one dataset and name the rows correspondingly
I have 3 vectors:
V <-structure(list(mean = 1.34944359241928, sd = 0.57779881866326, 
           `0.025quant` = 0.196903771571785, `0.5quant` = 1.35295469982876, 
           `0.975quant` = 2.48177705326348, mode = NA_real_, kld = 1.9807860333589e-08), row.names = "MULT", class = "data.frame")

PC <- structure(list(mean = 1.34944359241928, sd = 0.57779881866326, 
           `0.025quant` = 0.196903771571785, `0.5quant` = 1.35295469982876, 
           `0.975quant` = 2.48177705326348, mode = NA_real_, kld = 1.9807860333589e-08), row.names = "MULT", class = "data.frame")


IF <- structure(list(mean = 1.34909620780277, sd = 0.584070365393511, 
                 `0.025quant` = 0.187046377119461, `0.5quant` = 1.35203229998754, 
                 `0.975quant` = 2.4943145617015, mode = NA_real_, kld = 1.67173434130176e-08), row.names = "MULT", class = "data.frame")

I want to combine these 3 vectors into one dataset, where each vector corresponds to a separate row in a dataset, with a name of the vector (V, PC, IF) being in the first column.
I know how to combine them, but could not find a solution to name the rows according to the original vector.
Any suggestions, guys?

Using tibble
You can do this entirely in base R but I would use tibble. First tibble::lst() which automatically generates names from the names of the vectors. Then we can use the base R functions to bind them as rows with row names, and tibble::rownames_to_column() to generate the first column.
library(tibble)
lst(V, PC, IF) |>
    do.call(rbind, args = _) |>
    rownames_to_column("vec")

#   vec     mean        sd 0.025quant 0.5quant 0.975quant mode          kld
# 1   V 1.349444 0.5777988  0.1969038 1.352955   2.481777   NA 1.980786e-08
# 2  PC 1.349444 0.5777988  0.1969038 1.352955   2.481777   NA 1.980786e-08
# 3  IF 1.349096 0.5840704  0.1870464 1.352032   2.494315   NA 1.671734e-08

If you're using the tidyverse you could also do:
lst(V, PC, IF) |>
    dplyr::bind_rows(.id = "vec")

However, this doesn't strip your original row names attribute, You'd need to add another line to the pipe, so if you want to remove row names, I don't see any advantage to this approach.
base R
You can of course create a named list, list(V=V, PC=PC, IF=IF). But if we assume that's too much typing, you can write a function that automatically names the elements of your list, like tibble::lst() (although under the hood that uses quos()).
lst2 <- function(...) {
    setNames(
        list(...),
        as.list(match.call())[-1]
    )
}

This works because, as the R Language Definition states,

The components of a call object are accessed using a list-like syntax, and may in fact be converted to and from lists using as.list and as.call

We use as.list(match.call())[-1] to discard the first element, which is the function name itself, so in this case lst2. Then simply:
dat <- do.call(
    rbind,
    lst2(V, PC, IF)
)
cbind(vec = rownames(dat), dat)

#    vec     mean        sd 0.025quant 0.5quant 0.975quant mode          kld
# V    V 1.349444 0.5777988  0.1969038 1.352955   2.481777   NA 1.980786e-08
# PC  PC 1.349444 0.5777988  0.1969038 1.352955   2.481777   NA 1.980786e-08
# IF  IF 1.349096 0.5840704  0.1870464 1.352032   2.494315   NA 1.671734e-08


Using mget and cbind names to it.
> n <- c('V', 'PC', 'IF')
> cbind(names=n, do.call('rbind', mget(n)))
   names     mean        sd 0.025quant 0.5quant 0.975quant mode          kld
V      V 1.349444 0.5777988  0.1969038 1.352955   2.481777   NA 1.980786e-08
PC    PC 1.349444 0.5777988  0.1969038 1.352955   2.481777   NA 1.980786e-08
IF    IF 1.349096 0.5840704  0.1870464 1.352032   2.494315   NA 1.671734e-08

